# Get value from other script file variable Unity C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I have a weird question. I want to get value from other script file, but actually it is quick easy. But this time I have an another case.

For example:

I have `player.cs` that save the data with datatype dictionary

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class player : MonoBehaviour {

    public Dictionary <string, Dictionary <string, int> > product;

}
```

then I have `margaretShop.cs` that set the value of dictionary product

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class margaretShop : MonoBehaviour {
    player Player;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("player").GetComponent<player> ();

            setValue("A", "id", "10");
            setValue("A", "name", "A");
            setValue("A", "qty", "4");
            setValue("A", "price", "120");



    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void init() {
        if (Player.product != null) {
            return;
        }
        Player.product = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary <string, int> > ();
    }

    public int getValue(string nameproduct, string property) {
        init ();

        if (Player.product.ContainsKey (nameproduct) == false) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (Player.product [nameproduct].ContainsKey (property) == false) {
            return 0;
        }

        return Player.product [nameproduct] [property];
    }

    public void setValue(string nameproduct, string property, int value) {
        init ();

        if (Player.product.ContainsKey (nameproduct) == false) {
            Player.product[nameproduct] = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        }

        Player.product [nameproduct] [property] = value; // This store to player.cs file product
    }


    public string[] getProductName() {
        return Player.product.Keys.ToArray();

    }

}
```

and then last I call it with another script file `margaretSellScript.cs`

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class margaretSellScript : MonoBehaviour {
    margaretShop mShop;

    player Player;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        mShop = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("MargaretShop").GetComponent<margaretShop> ();
        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("player").GetComponent<player> ();

    Debug.Log("QTY : " + mShop.getValue ("A", "qty"));

    }                 
}
```

In this script: `Debug.Log("QTY : " + mShop.getValue ("A", "qty"));` why I can't get the value from player.cs product variable dictionary? The value must be **"4"** right?

***The error is*** `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

I have already call the gameobject like this at **margaretSellScript.cs** :

```
mShop = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("MargaretShop").GetComponent<margaretShop> ();
            Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("player").GetComponent<player> ();
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Find out if `mShop` is `nul` or if `getValue` is throwing the error message. You can do that by replacing `Debug.Log("QTY : " + mShop.getValue ("A", "qty"));` with `if(mShop ==null){Debug.Log("Null");}else{Debug.Log("Not Null");}` then let me know

Comment: Hi @Programmer, it is NULL. But i can't set manual if it is a prefab. So How ?

Comment: If it is null then this means that `margaretShop` script is not attached to the `MargaretShop` GameObject. So Attach `margaretShop`  to the `MargaretShop` GameObject. Let me know if that fixes your problem.

Comment: But i see it is attacted. Just i am not set it active until i press the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But i see it is attacted. Just i am not set it active until i press
>   the button.

That's the problem. The component must be `enabled` in order for `GetComponent<Script> ()` to find it. `Enable` it from the Editor as default. When game starts get the `reference` then `disable` it.

```
mShop = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MargaretShop").GetComponent<margaretShop>();
mShop.enabled = false; //disable it
```

If you have any code that runs in the `Start()` function of the `margaretShop` script, you can remove them and put them in a custom public function named `initScript()`.

Now, when you press the `Button`, you can activate it with `mShop.enabled = false;`, then call the `initScript()` function to initialize your variables in the `margaretShop` script. That's it.