# How do I get a value from another script in Unity (with an IEnumerator)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to get a value in a script from a different script. I have two scripts:

```
public class CargarDatos : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string[] fechas;
    public string dia;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://localhost/Linx/Fechas.php");
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        string fechasDatos = www.downloadHandler.text;
        print(fechasDatos);
        fechas = fechasDatos.Split(';');
        dia = GetValorDatos(fechas[0], "Dia:");
        //print(dia);
    }

    string GetValorDatos(string datos, string index)
    {
        string valor = datos.Substring(datos.IndexOf(index)+index.Length);
        if(valor.Contains("|"))
        {
           valor = valor.Remove(valor.IndexOf("|")); 
        }
        return valor;
    }
}
```

Here, as it is shown, a connection is established to a database and get a value (dia). This script is attached to the Main Camera, as I only want it to connect at the start of the game. Here, the function print(dia) returns the correct value, so this script works.

The problem is when I try to get the value in this script:

```
public class BarraExperiencia : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        print(GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<CargarDatos>().dia);
    }
}
```

This script is attached to a slider, and I have tried to print that to see if it works, but it doesn't print anything. What have I done wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get value from other script file variable Unity C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388550/get-value-from-other-script-file-variable-unity-c-sharp)

Comment: Not really, it's not the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get the "dia" value before the coroutine has finished. Try to print the value only after the coroutine is finished.

Also, it would be faster to use [FindObjectOfType](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) to get the component.

Comment: When I could print the value? It's the first time I have done this and I don't know when is the coroutine finished.

Answer (score 0):

The value is not available yet. I highly recommend you not use public variables and rather encapsulate access to the value in a property like:

```
        private string dia = null;
        public string Dia {
            get {
                if(dia != null) {
                    return dia;
                }

                UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get ("http://localhost/Linx/Fechas.php");
                yield return www.SendWebRequest ();
                string fechasDatos = www.downloadHandler.text;
                print (fechasDatos);
                fechas = fechasDatos.Split (';');
                dia = GetValorDatos (fechas[0], "Dia:");
            }
        }
```

**UPDATED**
Please take a look at the following example architecture for your scenario. We cannot encapsulate yield within the property as I originally suggested due to the async nature of Unity `UnityWebRequest`.

In the below, we call our service and pass in a callback of type `Action<User>` to run when the service completes. This callback can now do whatever is needed from your consuming component -  in the example, we update a `Text` component.

You can copy and paste these into your project and they will return sample data from Github.

MyService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

namespace MyCompany.MyGame {
    public class User {
        public string login;
    }

    public class MyService {
        public IEnumerator GetUser (Action<User> callback) {
            using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get ("https://api.github.com/users/octocat")) {
                yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest ();
                callback (JsonUtility.FromJson<User> (webRequest.downloadHandler.text));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Entry.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace MyCompany.MyGame {
    public class Entry : MonoBehaviour {
        MyService myService;

        [SerializeField]
        Text playerName;

        void Awake () {
            myService = new MyService ();
        }

        void Start () {
            StartCoroutine (myService.GetUser ((User result) => {
                Debug.Log (result);
                playerName.text = result.login;
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used your code and it gives me an error ("Cannot return a value from an iterator. Use the yield return statement to return a value, or yield break to end the iteration")

Comment: @velaskus please see the example above. You can paste into your project and step through in debugger to review. Entry.cs should be attached to a Gameobject in your scene.